# Go build & exec: fork/exec: permission denied

Tags: macos, go, exec, fork

I need to build a program using the Go toolchain and then execute it. For some reasons I get a permission error due the forking. Is there a way to circumvent this error or any best practice? I think my program does something similar with `Go test` tool, though `go test` doesn't get this kind of error.

```
package main

import(
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "flag"
    log "github.com/golang/glog"
)

func main(){
    flag.Parse()
    tdir := "abc"
    if err := os.MkdirAll(tdir, 0777); err !=nil{
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    f, err := os.Create(tdir + "/main.go")
    if err !=nil{
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    if err = f.Chmod(0777); err !=nil{
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    defer os.Remove(f.Name())
    if _, err = f.Write([]byte(tpl)); err !=nil{
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "-o", "edoc")
    cmd.Path = tdir
    b, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err !=nil{
        log.Errorf("%s, err %v", b, err)
        return
    }

}

var tpl = `package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "flag"
)

func main(){
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Printf("Hello World")

}`
```

Error:

```
E0202 18:24:42.359008   13600 main.go:36] , err fork/exec abc: permission denied
```

OS: OSX 10.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're changing the command path from the location of your `go` binary, to `abc`.

> ```
> type Cmd struct {
>         // Path is the path of the command to run.
>         //
>         // This is the only field that must be set to a non-zero
>         // value. If Path is relative, it is evaluated relative
>         // to Dir.
>         Path string
> ```

If you want to change the working directory, use [`Cmd.Dir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd)