# Command failed with fork/exec permission denied on MacOS?

Tags: macos, go

I have a go program that needs to execute another executable program, the program I want to execute from my go code is located in **/Users/myuser/bin/** directory and the full path to it would be **/Users/myuser/bin/prog**

The code is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
cmd := exec.Command("prog")
cmd.Dir = "/Users/myuser/bin/"
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("combined out:\n%s\n", string(out))
}
```

When I run the above code on MacOS Mojave I always get the following error:

> Command failed with fork/exec /Users/myuser/bin/: permission denied

I've seen other answers to similar errors such as [Go fork/exec permission denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943917/go-fork-exec-permission-denied-error) and [Go build & exec: fork/exec: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159117/go-build-exec-fork-exec-permission-denied) but I'm not sure if that's the case here.

Is it a permissions issue on my machine? or something else can be done from the code?

Comment: The error message is unlikely for the given code. Try run `go clean` and re-compile your code and trie again see if the error changes.

Comment: @leafbebop Thanks, I did go clean, now it shows me: Command failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it to work this way:

- I ran `go clean` as [leaf bebop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9143962/leaf-bebop) mentioned
- I changed the command execution implementation to:

```
    func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("prog")
        cmd.Dir = "/Users/myuser/bin/"
        var out bytes.Buffer
        var stderr bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &out
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, But in my case I was making a blunder. Instead of giving a path to the executable, I mistakenly provided the path of a directory.

Also, try checking the permissions of your binary file, if it was a file.

```
ls -l <path_to_binary>
```